# Can't define a div outside parent div

Tags: html, css

The project I have been working on has an HTML file that looks like this:

```
<div id="spn-service-provider-list">
   <div class="spnsearch">
        <i class="spnicon spn-icon-search"></i> 
                <input type="search" ng-model="spsearch" id="spsearch" placeholder="Search Providers" name="spsearch">
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to move **spnsearch** independently of the parent div, hence, wrote it outside the parent div, as:

```
<div class="spnsearch">
    <i class="spnicon spn-icon-search"></i> 
            <input type="search" ng-model="spsearch" id="spsearch" placeholder="Search Providers" name="spsearch">
</div>

<div id="spn-service-provider-list">
   .............
   ............
</div>
```

When I inspect the page in the browser, no change takes places. That is, **spn-service-provider-list** still contains the search box. Can someone please explain to me why is this happening? I am a beginner with UI development, so please bear with me if the question is elementary. Thanks!

Comment: So the resulting HTML is the same as your first example? Where do you change the HTML? What CMS/library do you use? Or is it just plain HTML?

Comment: You just change it in wrong place.

Comment: @lumio Yes, the resulting HTML is the same as my first one. I guess I need to change the JSP file as well.

Comment: @skobaljic Where should I change it?

Comment: Check if your CMS has templates/skins/themes or something, could be you just change default template which is not in use...